# How a visual basic 6.0 combo box can be used like Html select tag to show other data and after selecting store other data in value

Tags: mysql, combobox, vb6

I am working in `vb6` and I have a table with id and name:

```
Database mysql 5.5
Table : Employee
Field1 : Empid integer (primary, AI)
Field2 : EmpName varchar (20)
```

I want to use a `vb6` combobox to display `EmpName` to user and Store `Empid` when a user refers `combobox.value()`.

***Is it possible in vb6? Is there any alternate?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ComboBox.ItemData` property to store the numeric ID:

```
combobox.Add(rs("EmpName").Value)
combobox.ItemData(combobox.NewIndex) = rs("Empid").Value
```

To get the selected employee name:

```
strName = combobox.List(combobox.ListIndex)
```

To get the selected employee id:

```
intID = combobox.ItemData(combobox.ListIndex)
```